# Cordova Mms Plugin Error : mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to send the MMS to some "anyemail@gmail.com", I tried my device mms service (using device sms app) and it worked. So now I'am tring to do the same using myapp. So, I landed up to [cordova-MMS-Plugin](https://github.com/christyrajupaul/Phonegap-MMS-Plugin).

But it gave some error `MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting`. So I looked in `res/xml` there was no `mms_config.xml`. So I downloaded it from git repo [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms), and put it in `res/xml` folder. But still the same error.

Here is My Code, this code contains only javascript I used to call `send()` for sending MMS with some arguments.

```
sendSMS = function (phoneNo, data) {
  var that = this;
  window.module.exports.send(phoneNo,data,undefined,undefined,function () { 
    that.smsSent();
  },function (e) {
    that.failed(e); 
  });
}
```

Here is MMS-PLUGIN js File `sms.js`

```
var sms = {
   send: function(phone, message, imageFile, method, success, failure) {
    phone = sms.convertPhoneToArray(phone);

    cordova.exec(
        success,
        failure,
        'Sms',
        'send',
        [phone, message, imageFile, method]
    );
},

convertPhoneToArray: function(phone) {
    if(typeof phone === 'string' && phone.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
        phone = phone.split(',');
    }
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(phone) !== '[object Array]') {
        phone = [phone];
    }
    return phone;
  }
};
sms.install = function () {
  window.module.exports = sms;
}
cordova.addConstructor(sms.install);
```

Any body have any idea what I'm missing here.
One more thing it works when I send to a mobileNo instead of email.